# WinSock server is able to get incoming data but cannot connect to client

Tags: c++, winsock

I am working on a simple server program and it works perfectly using 127.0.0.1 but when I set the IP to a client (100.2.132.128) who is running the client the server only can receive and am unable to send. The code is mostly based off [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I used Wire shark to capture the traffic between [Wire Shark](http://i.gyazo.com/12333b545e9a114a48b99370c03aa076.png).
The source code for the server attempting to send data to the client:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define OUT_DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define OUT_DEFAULT_PORT "20000"

bool Send(std::string arg, std::string IP){

if (arg.size() > 250){
    return false;
}

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;

int iResult;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(IP.c_str(), OUT_DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server 
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    return 1;
}

char *cstr = InAppendSizePacket(arg);

iResult = send(ConnectSocket, cstr, (int)strlen(cstr), 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

char recvbuf[OUT_DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = OUT_DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

    if (iResult > 0){
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        if (recvbuf[0] == 'O' && recvbuf[1] == 'K'){
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (iResult == 0){
        printf("Connection closed\n");
        int debug = 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        int debug = 0;
    }
} while (iResult > 0);

std::cout << "The result is:" << recvbuf << std::endl;

iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

The source code for the client waiting to accept data from the server is:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define IN_DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define IN_DEFAULT_PORT "20000"

unsigned __stdcall FTPAcceptSession(void *data){
    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[IN_DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = IN_DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int iResult;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET)data;
    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection

    ClientQuarry NewPacket;

    int err = getpeername(ClientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &NewPacket.addr, &NewPacket.addr_len);

    if (err != 0) {
        // error, drop the packet.
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> ToDump;
    int amount = 0;

    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            std::string temp = PrependSizePacket(recvbuf);

            amount++;               

            ToDump.push_back(temp); //Add to the buffer.

        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else{
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            return 1;
        }

        char* LK = "OK";
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, LK, iResult, 0);

        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR || iSendResult == WSAEFAULT) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(ClientSocket);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI FileTransferProtocol(LPVOID lpParam){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, IN_DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;){
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        unsigned threadID;
        HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &FTPAcceptSession,      (void*)ClientSocket, 0, &threadID);
    }

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
     }
```

I added the program to firewall, open ports 20001 and 20000 for it. The server seems to timeout on the connect() request but I can't figure out why.

Comment: This is backwards from the usual meaning of "client" and "server" - the server is the process that accepts connections, and the client is the process that connects to the server.

Comment: The client sends a packet to the server the server responds. The problem is the server response never happens.

Comment: You do indeed have it backwards. You have your client code above listening and you have your server code connecting. This isn't right. Your client should be doing the connecting and requesting and the server responding. Read your post and you'll see.

Comment: I know but think about it. I have a client and a server and both have to send packets. When the client sends the connection to the server it works without any problems but when I send try to connect on a new port that the client is waiting on with the code above it just times out.